# Use Sidekiq to keep a cache of results full

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker, sidekiq

Say I have a particularly expensive calculation to perform during a specific user request. The plus side is that this calculation can be performed ahead of time, and pushed in a general queue for people to pull from.

Is there a way to use `Sidekiq` in a Ruby/Rails backend to keep this cache of results full to a certain level?  Where would I store the results of this calculation?

e.g.

1. On server load, calculate 20 sets of results, and cache somewhere.
2. On user request, pop off a result to allow for immediate server response.
3. Regenerate one set of results in the background to fill back up to 20 in the queue.

Obviously may need to use a different number than 20 depending on how long the computation takes, and rate of user requests, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious to know what kind of calculation actually fits this profile but that's not really important.

Since you are using Sidekiq (or would like to use Sidekiq) it means you have a Redis database. A Redis database is a great place to put this kind of info.

So you can just create a LIST in Redis of your results. During application startup fire of 20 sidekiq jobs to create your calculations. The worker doing the calculation can push the result onto the list in Redis.

As you handle requests, just pop a result off the list and queue another sidekiq job to make yourself a new calculation.

Comment: Haha - I can't believe that I didn't think of it this way. Thanks for that! The calculations are just base stats & math for simulations that can be extracted in a common fashion for every user, then built up from there.